# SQLAlchemy codec can't decode byte 0x81 with Oracle WE8ISO8859P1 encoding

Tags: python, oracle, encoding, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

Disclaimer: I struggle with encodings.

I'm using SQLAlchemy to pull some data from an Oracle 12 database with **WE8ISO8859P1** character set (according to **NLS_CHARACTERSET**)

Somewhere there is a value in the database (assuming a person's name) that when the value is passed to Python, it throws an error.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 4: character maps to <undefined>
```

Code is:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__= 'PERSON'

    id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    lastname = Column(String)
    firstname = Column(String)
    middlename = Column(String)
    active = Column(Integer)  
    sex = Column(String)
    dateofbirth = Column(String)

engine = create_engine('oracle://USER:PASS@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521/ORCL', echo=True)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

session = Session()

testList = []


for user in session.query(Person).all():
    testList.append(user)
```

Checking in oracle v$session_connect_info I see that the client running this code is connecting with character set **WE8MSWIN1252**

I know Python uses Unicode, so it looks like I have 3 different encodings that aren't matching, and I really don't know where to start.

Should I...

1. Try to change the encoding on the oracle client (Windows machine, yet I see other Windows clients connected with UTF-8)
2. Try to change the encoding in the `create_engine` script? (I tried to pass `encoding='WE8ISO8859P1'` and it didn't accept that.
3. Try to catch the error and change the value to something else.

Bonus: What exactly is 0x81? Maybe that shouldn't even be encoded in a person's name?

Comment: Please include the complete traceback.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options:

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect("user/pw@tns", encoding = "ISO-8859-1", nencoding = "UTF-8")
```

Or you can simply set the environment variables NLS_LANG and NLS_NCHAR

```
NLS_LANG=.WE8ISO8859P1
NLS_LNCHAR=AL32UTF8
```

Note that you can also use encoding = "UTF-8" in the cx_Oracle connect() method as ISO-8859-1 is easily converted to UTF-8. cx_Oracle will automatically take care of the conversion to string if you are using Python 3.